SQL for querying a graph structure (transitive closure problem)
We have a table that tracks all the Gift Cards used a By a Customer. It is a Many to Many Relationship, a Customer may use multiple Gift Cards, and a single Gift Card may be used by Used by Multiple Customers (partial balance etc.)
We need to create a Database View that can capture this many-to-many association as a network which is a single record. The single records should have all the Gift Cards by all the Customers that have used those Gift Cards.
I am not sure how to implement this in SQL. Please advise.



Customer ID
Gift Cards Acct Number




AAA
1111


BBB
1111


AAA
2222


CCC
2222


DDD
3333



Information we need to surface in the VIEW:



Customer IDs
Gift Cards Acct Numbers




AAA, BBB, CCC
1111;2222


DDD
3333;




Not sure why there are so many close votes on this question.  However, what you are looking for is transitive closure, which isn't easy in SQL.  It would be helpful if you'd choose a specific platform that you are using, though, as leveraging specific functions might be useful and you've chosen every cloud SQL tag available to you.

Hi @MikeWalton The reason I these four tags is that we have all these platforms available for this analysis. So we are open to implementing this in any platform.

@SaqibAli are those the only four platforms available? It's just that Redshift and BigQuery are on two different cloud providers so it seems like you might be at quite an early stage if you have such freedom over infrastructure. Might a Graph database be a better fit? Neo4j have a hosted offering, Neo4j Aura, for example.

See example (PostgreSql and BigQuery).
Idea is

Traversing an undirected graph along all paths from each node (kern). Here it is possible to optimize the selection of suitable nodes for traversing the graph.
Assembling (grouping) paths for each kern. Only one node combination is possible for each closed complete group.
We leave only unique paths.

With test data
with recursive gifts as(
  select 'AAA' CustomerId, 1111 GiftCardsAcctNumber 
  union all select 'BBB',1111
  union all select 'AAA',2222
  union all select 'CCC',2222
  union all select 'DDD',3333
  union all select 'EEE',4444
  union all select 'FFF',1111
  union all select 'FFF',4444
)

and recursive query
, r as(
  select 0 lvl,t1.CustomerId kern,t1.CustomerId,t1.GiftCardsAcctNumber GiftId
     ,concat(t1.CustomerId,'-') custS
     ,concat(t1.GiftCardsAcctNumber,'-') giftS
  from gifts t1  
  union all
  select lvl+1,r.kern,g.CustomerId
    ,case when g.GiftCardsAcctNumber=r.GiftId then r.GiftId
     else g.GiftCardsAcctNumber 
     end GiftId
    ,case when g.GiftCardsAcctNumber=r.GiftId then concat(r.custS,'-',g.CustomerId)
     else  r.custS
     end custS
    ,case when g.CustomerId=r.CustomerId then concat(r.giftS,'-',g.GiftCardsAcctNumber) 
     else r.giftS
     end giftS
  from r inner join gifts g 
    on (g.GiftCardsAcctNumber=r.GiftId and g.CustomerId<>r.CustomerId 
         and r.custS not like concat('%',g.CustomerId,'%'))
      or (g.CustomerId=r.CustomerId and g.GiftCardsAcctNumber<>r.GiftId 
           and r.giftS not like concat('%',g.GiftCardsAcctNumber,'%'))
  where (g.CustomerId<>r.CustomerId or g.GiftCardsAcctNumber<>r.GiftId)
)
select distinct cs,gs
from(
  select kern,string_agg(distinct customerId,'-' order by customerid) cs
    ,string_agg(distinct giftId,'-' order by giftid) gs
  from(                                    -- varchar  
     select kern,customerid,cast(giftId as string) giftid
     from( select * from r  )x
     group by kern,customerid,giftid
  ) y
  group by kern
)z




Row
cs
gs




1
AAA-BBB-CCC-EEE-FFF
1111-2222-4444


2
DDD
3333



Fiddle for explain
